# Bankteller console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, console-application

I'm making a simple application to simulate the **bankteller problem**.
What I'm trying to simulate is:

You have 4 counters in a store. 1 counter is open. Customers start coming in and enter the line for the first counter.

When the fourth customer enters the line for the first counter, another counter should open. The line should be equally divided between the 2 counters.When the customer at the second counter is helped and no new customers enter the line, the counter should close. Basically 4 is too many.

I can't seem to figure it out. I know I need to use a queue. But how? Could someone give me an example in console application? Preferable C#.

Thanks in advance.

Here is what I tried so far,

register class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegisterCounter
{
    class Register
    {
    private int customerCount;
    public Queue<Customer> Line = new Queue<Customer>();

    public Register()
    {
        customerCount = 2;
    }

    public Register(int customerCount)
    {
        this.customerCount = customerCount;
    }

    public int getCustomers()
    {
        return customerCount;
    }
}
```

}

Customer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RegisterCounter
{
    class Customer
    {
    private int checkoutTime;

    public Customer()
    {
        checkoutTime = 3;
    }

    public Customer(int checkoutTime)
    {
        this.checkoutTime = checkoutTime;
    }

    public int GetCheckoutTime()
    {
        return checkoutTime;
    }
}
```

}

Register manager:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace RegisterCounter
{
    class RegisterManager
    {
        public List<Register> registers = new List<Register>();
        Register r1 = new Register();
        Customer c1 = new Customer();


        public RegisterManager()
        {
            registers.Add(r1);
        }

        public void ManageCustomers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < registers.Count; i++)
        {
            registers.Insert(i, new Register());

            if (i / 4 <= registers..Line.Count)
            { 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Questions for 'how to do my homework' are not well received here. Make a start and then you can ask here about very specific problems.

Comment: I understand your point but i can assure you this is an application I'm planning to make for the store i work in. Its just a stupid application. I've already tried a couple of things but i can't seem to work it out.

Comment: Can you show some "sketch-work" or "pseudo-codes" that you have tried out? It doesn't have to be *John Skeet type of code*. But you have to convince the community you, yourself have understood the requirements and the question.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact specification of the bankteller problem but I would have thought the best approach to any queuing system is a single queue that only separates at the point of service. So you don't split the queue when you open another counter, you just have two counters taking from the front of the queue instead of one. So much more fair than any other system and should work fine with four counters - it will of course fall apart more with larger numbers of counters where the logistics become trickier.

Comment: @TimvanGool just google. This is a queue 101 exercise. It really looks like you're asking for us to do your homework.

Comment: Why is this `using System.Threading.Tasks;` in your code?

Comment: Its in the code by default but I don't think I will need to use it. @bonCodigo