# Unexpected output in array

Tags: c#, arrays, console, queue

So I saw this question today. [Bankteller console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674705/bankteller-console-application)

And I thought I'm going to try and make that since it is a common problem.
I already got some sort of working output however it is not formatted the way I expected it to be.

here is my updated code:

Customer Class:

```
class Customer
{

    private string name;
    private int checkOutTime;

    public Customer()
    {
        name = "john";
        checkOutTime = 500;
    }

    public Customer(string name, int checkOutTime)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.checkOutTime = checkOutTime;
    }
}
```

Register class:

```
class Register
{
    public Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];
    public string[] names = { "jan", "peter", "hans", "karel", "tim", "rick", "Lewbert", "borat", "Sharkisha", "Bobo" };
    public Random rnd = new Random();
    public Queue<Customer> Line = new Queue<Customer>();

    public Register(int amount, Register[] r, int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            customers[i] = new Customer(names[rnd.Next(0, 8)], rnd.Next(900, 5000));
            Line.Enqueue(customers[i]);
            if (Line.Count % 4 == 0)
            {
                id++;
                amount = amount - 4;
                r[id] = new Register(amount, r, id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program cs:

```
class Program
{        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Register[] bankRegisters = new Register[10];
        Register r = new Register(12, bankRegisters, 0);
    }
}
```

The output I get is nested. It shows that I have a register inside my register instead of multiple registers in the bank.

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't see any code in your post that produces output.  What output are you getting and where does it come from?

Comment: Could it be the Main method producing that extra register (In case it  does inherit)?

Comment: If you don't want to have registers within registers, don't do it. Hint: Your class Program, and hence your class Register, has a declaration for property *bankRegisters*. Each Register object you create maintains its own *bankRegisters* array. Take a pen and draw a diagram with the program flow and which object owns which particular *bankRegisters* array, and you will see...

Comment: Register should almost certainly not inherit from Program.  A Register is not a more specific type of Program, after all.

The logic to populate the bankRegisters array should be in the program class, not in the Registers constructor.

Comment: @elgonzo Hmm but there is no declaration in my register class right? I am adding it to the array I made in my program.cs. I tried drawing my program flow but mayby it's just a bit of knowledge I am missing. Can you please teach me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know about inheritance? (look at your class declaration `class Register : Program` -- also, heed phoog's advice that usually a class should not inherit from Program)

Comment: @elgonzo yes a bit, I kinda forgot that I had that part inherited. I tried a lot of things im afraid I left it there.

Comment: allright, So I stopped inheriting from program. I gave the bankRegisters to the class trough the constructor. Only now it's not nested but there is only one register in the array and it's in the 3th position.

Comment: Can someone point me my mistakes with an explenation please? Or a source where I can find answers.